# Ideal maximal with respect to the property that it does not contain a given ideal and Jacobson rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

I would like to prove the following claim:

> Given an arbitrary commutative ring $R$ and a radical ideal $I$, there exist a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ maximal among those not containing $I$.

This is a special case of lemma 6.4.5.1 in Grothendieck's EGA 1, rephrased for affine schemes, but I would like to prove it with ring-theoretic arguments.

If $I$ is a finitely generated ideal one can easily conclude using Zorn's lemma. However I can't find a general argument for arbitrary ideals. I suspect that it could be somewhat hard, because this fact can be used to prove important theorems about Jacobson rings, which have non-trivial direct proofs.

Comment: If you take $I$ to be the nilradical, isn't this just false?  There can't exist such a prime ideal because the set of such prime ideals would be empty.